# How to enable multiple roles for a MVCsitemapNode-ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using `MVCsiteMapNode` to display the menu for various roles.

For single role Iam using the following.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="NewMenuItem" controller="TestMenu" 
                action="Index" Roles="SystemAdmin"/>
```

For Multiple Roles, I want to display the same menu.  It tried this:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="NewMenuItem" controller="TestMenu" 
                action="Index" Roles="SystemAdmin,NewRole"/>
```

It does not display if the current user is a member of the SystemAdmin role.

In my helper class I am using the following

```
if (isSystemAdmin)
{
    if (node["roles"].Equals("SystemAdmin"))
    {
        DisplayMenu(sb, node);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if (node["roles"].Contains("SystemAdmin")) ...
```